# Network connection needs to be brought up a second time at boot for networking to work on Debian 7

Tags: debian, ethernet

I am using Debian 7 on some newly designed hardware.  After bootup the Ethernet is not setup correctly, but if I run an "/etc/init.d/network restart" or do an if down/up after bootup then it works.  Does anyone know how to make the Ethernet work on the first boot without this 2nd stage configuration step?

The system does seem to take a few seconds to see that the network is alive, as is shown below.  Maybe this delay is causing some type of startup problem with Debian?

```
> [   18.343688] net eth0: CPSW phy found : id is : 0x7c0f1 [  
> 18.358673] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready [   21.342437] PHY: 0:00 - Link is Up - 10/Full [   21.347167]
> ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready [....] Configuring
> network interfaces...[   24.365051] net eth0: CPSW phy found : id is :
> 0x7c0f1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this bug too on my am335x-based device only when I enabled both cpu frequency scaling and PREEMPT. I chose to disable PREEMPT as a workarround.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! This may solve the question, but we need instructions to offer a proper upvote. Can you please [edit] your answer to add more information, such as what that switch does, where you change it, how you found out that was the solution, etc? We want to help more than just the person having the problem *right now*

Comment: "We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is correct, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed."